# Jquery getting attribute of selected object and applying it to another object

Tags: jquery

Building a simple image slider/gallery.  I have some simple replace code, nothing fancy.

```
<script>
$(".imgt").click(function(){
    var newsrc = (this).attr("src");
    $("#imgb").attr("src","newsrc");
});
</script>
```

It's the var and the call to the var that I'm unsure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
$(".imgt").click(function() {
    $("#imgb").prop("src", this.src);
});
```

Comment: Much thanks.  Been working in PHP too long.  Syntax is getting rusty.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".imgt").click(function(){
    var newsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#imgb").attr("src", newsrc);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#imgb").attr("src","newsrc");
```

supposed to be

```
$("#imgb").attr("src",newsrc);
```

**Supposed to be without the Quotes..**

```
Also missing the **$** before this var newsrc = (this).attr("src");
                                                ^
                                              Missing here
```

Also better to use native DOM Objects if available..

```
$(".imgt").click(function(){
    var newsrc = this.src;
    $("#imgb").attr("src",newsrc);
});
```